# Directive export data angular 2

Tags: angular, directive

I've got some troubles with sending data from directive to component, directive works well, everytime I click on any input it draws a message on console, there is the code:

```
    import {Component, HostListener, Directive, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: 'input',
})
export class ListeningToHostComponent {
    name = '';
    @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
    onClick(btn) {//I would like to export this.name everytime this function is calles
        this.name = btn.name;
        console.log("name of div:" + btn.name);
    }
}
```

I dont even know if it's possible I tried to use standard methods of @input and @output. It's angular 2.4.1 Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your directive is child of your component you can use `EventEmitter` with `@Output`

```
import {Component, HostListener, Directive, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: 'input',
})
export class ListeningToHostComponent {
    name = '';
    @output() notify: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
    onClick(btn) {//I would like to export this.name everytime this function is calles
        this.name = btn.name;
        console.log("name of div:" + btn.name);
        this.notify.emit('Click from directive');
    }
}
```

Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-selector',
  template: `<div>  
  <h1>I'm a container component</h1>
  <directive-selector (notify)='onNotify($event)></directive-selector>
</div>  `,
})
export class ParentComponent {  
  onNotify(message:string):void {
    alert(message);
  }
}
```